# How to know the code base of a Magento mobile site?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, theme

The magento store, I am working, has a mobile site for mobile users. like, **example.bmobilized.com**. I can't find the **code base of this mobile site**. However I have searched and come up with the following..

1.There is no exception theme in System > Configuration > Design
2.There is a menu called "mobile" in admin section under which "manage app", "submission history","message template","message queue" are present with no records.

I doubt it has completely a different code base.
But **How can I find** that ? Is it using magento or any other platform ?

Comment: Are you asking about a mobile application like one developed in IOS or a Mobile site that is primarily HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found the following..

**www.bmobilized.com** is a website which converted the web application to the mobile site. It has features to customize its layout, adding extra thing in the mobile view as per requirement.
So anything related to design issue for mobile can be modified by going to its bmobilized account dashboard and can modify there.